# How to extract "nextPageToken" string from httr GET response in R console?

Tags: r, youtube-api, httr, jsonlite

I'm trying to extract ALL comments for YouTube videos using the YouTube Data API. I'm using `httr` to run my http `GET` query, which outputs the response in the R console.

How could I please access the nextPageToken string outputted in the response in the R console? I need to extract this in an automated fashion so that I can continue to rerun my query and add a `pageToken=[nextPageTokenString]` argument until it is undefined, meaning that all comments for that video have been extracted.

Note that I can save this query output as a "List of 10" object in my environment, from which I can call out many headers or convert variables to a data frame. However, the 'nextPageToken' header is not accessible from that stored list.

Here's my query on an example video ID. Note that this requires a Google API key in order to run:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
GET("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=[MyGoogleAPIKey]&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=kffacxfA7G4&maxResults=15")
```

This yields the following output, where I'd like to save the "nextPageToken" string:

```
  Date: 2019-08-20 15:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 18.2 kB
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
 "etag": "\"0UM_wBUsFuT6ekiIlwaHvyqc80M/DpUxU7iuAG44hC52yMW1GzpD7zs\"",
 "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMGV3a0U3SzNhazR2bmRsdG1lNXNHYXVtdUF1cDlRemZnR01CRjdnaHFXYTBKRHA5anAtSllmZ2hSakdHeTVnQmJyRmlYbENlREp0cTk0YjVOOGFHdDU3SEw0T3NtT3FicThMS0RvOHFrdE9NUGJrMDliR01fUDVTa24=",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 15,
  "resultsPerPage": 15
 },
 "items": [
  {
```

Many thanks in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of how the response actually appears. It is possible you can apply regex to extract the token string by pattern matching. Test the length of the matches to see if string is present. I give a pattern for if there is whitespace and if there isn't whitespace before the "token". It probably possible to combine these two into one but I rather suspect only one is needed.

```
library(stringr)

s <- paste0(
'Date: 2019-08-20 15:37',
'Status: 200',
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Size: 18.2 kB',
'{',
'"kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",',
  '"etag": "\"0UM_wBUsFuT6ekiIlwaHvyqc80M/DpUxU7iuAG44hC52yMW1GzpD7zs\"",',
  '"nextPageToken":"QURTSl9pMGV3a0U3SzNhazR2bmRsdG1lNXNHYXVtdUF1cDlRemZnR01CRjdnaHFXYTBKRHA5anAtSllmZ2hSakdHeTVnQmJyRmlYbENlREp0cTk0YjVOOGFHdDU3SEw0T3NtT3FicThMS0RvOHFrdE9NUGJrMDliR01fUDVTa24=",',
  '"pageInfo": {',
    '"totalResults": 15,',
    '"resultsPerPage": 15',
  '},',
  '"items": [',
    '{')

x <- str_match_all(s,'"nextPageToken":"(.*?)"') #no white space before "token"
token_no_whitespace <- x[[1]][,2]
#test if character(0) i.e. no match so pattern and therefore we assume nextPageToken not present
print(length(token_no_whitespace))

x <- str_match_all(s,'"nextPageToken":\\s+"(.*?)"') #white space before "token"
token_whitespace <- x[[1]][,2]
print(length(token_whitespace))
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, RegEx could be another option, thanks for providing the code. I actually ended up using the curl and fromJOSN packages and was able to extract the nextPageToken by calling it out of the list object - not sure why this is not an option in httr..

Comment: I forgot to say it would be interesting to see your solution. You can post and accept your own answer.